# Restrict access to only company employees from anywhere in the world

Tags: amazon-ec2

I want to restrict access to a webpage on a AWS EC2 instance, to only company employees, which are spread all over the world.  I have successfully whitelisted the UK offices, but i haven't for colleagues in Asia and Europe.

Rather than adding IP's daily, which also changes for the user, i want a system which can verify the employees.  Poor design.

I was thinking of having a Cognito User Pool and Identify Pool.  Or a VPN for user to login.

Have people had similar issues and how have they overcome them.  Any advice will be appericated.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Cognito would be a perfect solution for this. You can scan the user's E-Mail in the `Pre-Authentication` Lambda Trigger, and based on the user's E-Mail ID and other login parameters, you could allow or deny the Authentication Event.

For more information on the Pre-Authentication Lambda Trigger and sample codes, I would recommend you to go through this official [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-authentication.html).